# Make fontawesome icon hover with entire <a on navigation menu

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

Please help me on how make font awesome icon hover with <a link on navigation menu

I've tried:

li a.sc-ico:hover, .fa-windows:hover:before {color:blue!important;}

It worked but the hover effect worked on fontawesome icon only, I need fontawesome hover when I hover on the entire <a link.

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to target the hover on the a tag.

```
a:hover .fa-windows:before { color: blue }
```

if that doesn't work, try thorw in an important tag.